# Microsoft Office 2010 with PlayOnLinux won't install because of language incompatibility

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I want to install Microsoft Office 2010 (because you cannot use open source programs in business life now, can you?)
I installed Wine and PlayOnLinux and got my setup.exe file for 32bit Version of Microsoft Office 2010 Home and Student in German.

Apparently this is a problem. Microsoft Office refuses to install because "Installation language is not supported".

I also tried the English version. The installation stops with the same error notice "Installation language is not supported"

Does anyone have an idea how I can get around this weird problem?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, system language is German.

Comment: Use a Virtual Box and a Windows XP installation.

Comment: try office 2007